# Re-sizing Image Width Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, popupwindow

I am trying to re-size an image in a popup. The original image is 6000 x 4000.  I do a check to see if the image is greater than 500, and if so I just try and set the image to 500.  Trying to set it using 'this', makes the pop open in a tab and the image is still its original size.  If I try and set the image not using 'this', the pop up works as intended regarding where it is positioned on screen and the size of the box, but the image, is still its original size--6000 x 4000. (PS: I have to use ES5 as well.)

What gives?
Thanks,
CM

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"><!--
    // let i=0;
      function resize() {
          console.log("Testing");
          let i=0;
    
          if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 6.0') != -1 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('SV1') != -1) {
              i=30; //This browser is Internet Explorer 6.x on Windows XP SP2
          } else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 6.0') != -1) {
              i=0; //This browser is Internet Explorer 6.x
          } else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
              i=25; //This browser is Firefox on Windows
          } else if (window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Mozilla') != -1 && window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows") != -1) {
              i=45; //This browser is Mozilla on Windows
          } else {
              i=80; //This is all other browsers including Mozilla on Linux
          }
    
              var imgWidth = document.images[0].width;
              var imgHeight = document.images[0].height;
              console.log("Original image width is: " + imgWidth);
              console.log("Original image height is: " + imgHeight);
    
              if(imgWidth > 500){
    
                  //Shrink the image to size of popup frame
                  this.imgWidth = 500;
                  this.imgHeight = 500;
                  console.log("Adjusted image width is: " + imgWidth);
                  console.log("Adjusted image height is: " + imgHeight);
    
                  //Get display/screen width and height
                  var screenWidth  = screen.width;
                  var screenHeight = screen.height;
                  console.log("Screen width is: " + screenWidth);
                  console.log("Screen height is: " + screenHeight);
    
                  //Set popup position on display/screen
                  var leftpos =  screenWidth / 2 ;
                  var toppos  =  screenHeight / 2 - imgHeight / 2;
                  console.log("Left position is: " + leftpos);
                  console.log("Top position is: " + toppos);
    
                  //Set popup frame width and height equal to adjusted image width and height
                  var frameWidth  =  imgWidth;
                  var frameHeight =  imgHeight+i;
                  console.log("Frame width is: " + frameWidth);
                  console.log("Frame height is: " + frameHeight);
                  window.moveTo(leftpos, toppos);
                  window.resizeTo(frameWidth,frameHeight+i);
              }
              else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth) {
                var imgHeight = document.images[0].height + 40 - i;
                var imgWidth = document.images[0].width + 20;
                var height = screen.height;
                var width = screen.width;
                var leftpos = width / 2 - imgWidth / 2;
                var toppos = height / 2 - imgHeight / 2;
                frameWidth = imgWidth;
                frameHeight = imgHeight + i;
                window.moveTo(leftpos, toppos);
                window.resizeTo(frameWidth, frameHeight + i);
              } else if (document.body) {
                window.resizeTo(document.body.clientWidth, document.body.clientHeight - i);
              }
        self.focus();
      }//end resize() function
    //--></script>
```

Comment: You set variables to the integer value 500, you never actually change the DOM element object containing the image.

Comment: document.getElementById(#popupImg).width.style="500px" didn't work.

Comment: That is not a valid statement. try `document.getElementById('popupImg').style.width="500px"`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var imgWidth = document.images[0].style.width;
```

instead of

```
var imgWidth = document.images[0].width;
```